# Why does a switch statement on a string fail when the value comes from ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, razor

I have the following code in a CSHTML razor page:

```
@{
    var sort = ViewBag.Sort.ToString();
    switch (sort)
    {
        case "None": Html.Action("SortNone"); break;
        case "Name": Html.Action("SortName"); break;
        case "Date": Html.Action("SortDate"); break;
    }
}
```

However, this is failing with a Compiler Error Message:

```
CS0151: A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type
```

But sort is a string!  Rewriting this as a series of if/else statements works, but is not as elegant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try casting, the compiler doesn't know the return type of ToString() because it is dynamic.

```
var sort = (string)ViewBag.Sort.ToString();
```

Comment: OK, that makes the least amount of sense of everything I've ever known... but it works!  I'd get into a philosophical discussion on why ToString() doesn't just return a string, but I probably don't need to know...

Comment: Because it is dynamic the method will be bound at runtime, there isn't anything stopping a new implementation of ToString that returns something other than a string. You could use this ((object)ViewBag.Sort).ToString()